# In C++ does std::multiset keep a stable sorting order?

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I have two items, a and b, that compare the same. So a < b is false, and b < a is false. If these items are inserted into a std::multiset (or std::multimap) as keys, do I have any guarantees of their final sorted order?

I've checked a couple of references, but I couldn't find the answer. I'm tempted to think that there are no guarantees and that it's left up to each particular implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does std::multiset guarantee insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643473/does-stdmultiset-guarantee-insertion-order)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20130509163609/http://objectmix.com/c/26102-stl-multimap-insert-duplicate-keys-ordering-stable.html) implies that it is not guaranteed by the current standard but is met by all known current implementations, and gives a link to the C++0x draft standard that includes a guarantee.

Comment: For the record, the C++0x guarantee is "insert at upper bound."

Comment: Awesome.  We aren't using C++11 yet, but I'm going to be adding a unit test to our test suite to ensure the compiler's behavior across the versions we use.

Comment: @katta dang, that was the most aggressively nasty site I've ever browsed to. I'll fix the link ASAP.