# Does std::multiset guarantee insertion order?

Tags: c++, stl, data-structures, standard-library

I have a `std::multiset` which stores elements of `class A`. I have provided my own implementation of `operator<` for this class. My question is if I insert two equivalent objects into this multiset is their order guaranteed? For example, first I insert a object `a1` into the set and then I insert an equivalent object `a2` into this set. Can I expect the `a1` to come before `a2` when I iterate through the set? If no, is there any way to achieve this using multiset?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In C++03 you are not guaranteed that `insert` and `erase` preserve *relative ordering*. However, this is changed in C++0x:

> n3092, §23.2.4/4: An associative container supports unique keys if it may contain at most one element for each key. Otherwise, it supports equivalent keys. The set and map classes support unique keys; the multiset and multimap classes support equivalent keys. **For multiset and multimap, insert and erase preserve the relative ordering of equivalent elements.** <sub>Emphasis mine.</sub>

This is discussed in this [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#233). [This page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1780.html) is the collection of comments on the issue, it's well-written and quite fleshed-out. (I very much recommend reading this one over the previous "overview" link.)

From that comment page you'll find a comparison of current implementations, so you can check if the implementations you intend to use follow what you expect.

I can't think of a way to force the ordering you want off the top of my head. :/

Comment: Not using multiset either. `std::map<A, std::vector<A> >` would be my best bet at the moment...

Comment: @Matt: Yea, it's too bad to get the behavior you'd have to basically do multiset by hand :/

Comment: N1780 and DR 371 clearly say all current implementations provide stability, it's a natural property of RB trees. But the question isn't about stability of existing elements, it's whether `a2` gets inserted before or after `a1`, and the answer is after (true in practice in C++03, guaranteed in C++11). You can use an insertion hint to insert before existing elements if different behaviour is desired.

Comment: @JonathanWakely BTW please review http://stackoverflow.com/tags/template-templates/info

Comment: Does that quote really guarantee that _insertion order_ is preserved though? The way I read it, it only guarantees that the order of equivalent elements _already in the `multimap`_ aren't changed by `insert` or `erase`. This interpretation also seems to match the concerns raised in the defect report: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#371

Comment: @knatten: I think you're right. It is the intent this be the case, but it is still underspecified.

Answer (score 3):

Taking into account that `a1` and `a2` would compare equal in your example, and what is actually stored in the `std::multiset` are copies of `a1` and `a2`, I don't really know how would you know which is which.

If you can tell the difference, maybe `class A` was not well designed in the first place. So `std::multiset` does not guarantee such a thing.

Comment: I think my example was not clear enough. Lets say I have class person which has various attributes such as age, name etc. Now lets a I have many person objects and want to create multiset of persons sorted on age. I believe this is a genuine requirement. My question is if the two persons have same age is their order guaranteed as the input order?

Comment: The predicate supplied to the multiset only requires that there be a partial ordering.  If `a1 < a2` and `a2 < a1` both evaluate to false, that does not indicate that `a1 == a2` would evaluate to true.  The objects `a1` and `a2` are equivalent but are not necessarily equal.

Comment: @Naveen: As GMan has explained in his answer, this is guaranteed only from C++0x forward (I did not know they had introduced this guarantee, by the way; since this standard is not yet published, currently it is not guaranteed).

Comment: @Aeth: Yes, you are right. But usually (emphasis on "usually") it is not a good idea to have a class where all operators <, > and == return false for two valid objects. Sooner or later, this will lead to unexpected behaviour when somebody tries to use your class in a way you did not expect.

Comment: @Gorpik: I concur whole-heartedly with what you are saying about the comparison and equality operators.  The OP has not stated, though, whether the greater-than and equality operators have even been defined for his types.  For his example with people and their ages, I would not even use a less-than operator.  It seems as though the operator method was defined solely for use with the multiset.  I would prefer to define a different method such as `is_younger` and use that as the predicate for the multiset.  That way there is less confusion about the meaning of the method.

Comment: @Aeth: Indeed, using a predicate is the right thing here. In this case, I agree with anything else you said.

Answer (score 1):

std::multimap does not guarante this.
If you can express your `operator<` using an integer via a function e.g. `int A::orderingInt()`, you could use a

```
std::multiset<MyCustom> myset;
```

with

```
class MyCustom : public std::vector<A> {}
```

with overloaded

```
bool operator<(const MyCustom& a, const MyCustom& b) {
   // theoretically empty MyCustom should not occure
   return a[0].orderingInt() < b[0].orderingInt();
}
```

Of course adding and iteration would be different now:

```
A a;
myset[a.orderingInt()].push_back(a);

// groups with "small" elements first
for(std::multiset<MyCustom>::iterator it=myset.begin(); it!=myset.end(); it++) {
    // those elements are "equal"
    for(std::vector<A>::iterator jt=it->begin(); jt->end(); jt++) { 
         // use A& a = *jt;
    }
}
```