# Will std::multimap preserve the insert order if the key of 2 elements equal to each other?

Tags: c++, stl

I am wondering whether this is true? If it is, is this behavior guaranteed by the c++ standard?

Comment: Duplicate of [Does std::multiset guarantee insertion order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643473/does-stdmultiset-guarantee-insertion-order)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The elements in a `std::map` must have unique keys, so... no.

The `std::multimap` container allows multiple values mapped to one key.  When iterating over a `std::multimap` the elements are ordered by key, but the order of elements having the same key is not specified.

Note that in the latest draft of the forthcoming C++0x standard (N3092), the relative ordering of elements with the same key *is* guaranteed (so, at some point, you'll be able to rely on this behavior).

Comment: Thanks. I mean multimap in my previous post.

Comment: this statement seems different from the last proposed new standard that I have (but that is 21 months old (N2798=08-0308))

I quote:

For multiset and multimap, insert and erase preserve the relative ordering of equivalent elements. page 768

If a range containing elements equivalent to t exists in a_eq, t is inserted at the end of that range.

page 771

Comment: @pgast:  Very interesting.  That language is in the C++0x FCD (N3092).  However, it is not the case in the current C++ standard (C++03) that the relative ordering is maintained.  Thanks for pointing out that change.

Comment: @PhilLello: C++0x was later named C++11, so yes, the ordering is preserved in C++11.