# Preserve order of elements in copy from a multiset to another multiset

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 2 std::multiset

```
multiset<myObject *,dfa_ptr_states_less> m1;
multiset<myObject *,dfa_ptr_states_less> m2;
```

where I defined in an other file (myObject.h ) the Comparison function

```
struct dfa_ptr_states_less
{
   bool operator()(const myObject *l, const myObject *r) const
   {
       return ( l->get_num_states() < r->get_num_states() );
   };
};
```

where get_num_states is a field of myObject class.

m2 is empty. m1 point to dynamics objects. I have to do a copy of m1 in m2,namely a shallow copy of pointers from m1 to m2.

```
for(auto &ptr : m1)
   m2.insert(ptr);
```

Simple but my doubt is: The order of elements in m1 is preserved in m2? If not, how can I do? (For my purposes the order is very important)

UPDATE:
Maybe is it possible do:

```
m2=m1
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does std::multiset guarantee insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643473/does-stdmultiset-guarantee-insertion-order)

Comment: Re your update, yes, that would make more sense. Have you tried it? See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset `The order of the elements that compare equivalent is the order of insertion and does not change. (since C++11)`

Comment: @underscore_d Yes, now I tried it. It works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the order is preserved on copy (as well as on iteration and insertion).

Yes, `multiset` supports copy assignment.

Comment: And what happen to myObjects pointers? I want a shallow copy.  Does operator=  do  this?

Comment: @Umbert Nothing happens to them. Copying does not modify the source object. There is also no difference between a shallow and deep copy of a pointer (or any fundamental type).