# Get first N elements in a C++ multiset

Tags: c++, multiset

How can I get the first N elements from a multiset structure, without constantly getting the first (.begin()) element and then erasing it?

I just want to sum the first N elements without affecting the multiset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I just want to sum the first N elements without affecting the multiset.

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

// ...

int sum = std::accumulate(my_set.begin(), std::next(my_set.begin(), N));
```

`std::next` is a C++11 library addition. Here is a solution for older compilers:

```
std::multiset<int>::iterator it = my_set.begin();
std::advance(it, N);
int sum = std::accumulate(my_set.begin(), it);
```

Both solutions iterate over the multiset twice. If you want to prevent that, use a manual loop:

```
int sum = 0;
std::multiset<int>::iterator it = my_set.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    sum += *it++;
}
```

Comment: It says "next" is undefined, or smth like that

Comment: I "solved" the problem by manually iterating through first N elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the `multiset` like you would over any other container, and stop once you've seen `n` elements.

Comment: If I iterate I will get the elements in order?

Comment: Comfortably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530462/in-c-does-stdmultiset-keep-a-stable-sorting-order