# Neatest way to loop over a range of integers

Tags: c++

Since C++11 introduced the range-based for loop ([range-based for in c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005835/range-based-for-in-c11)), what is the neatest way to express looping over a range of integers?

Instead of

```
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
```

I'd like to write something like

```
for (int i : range(0,n))
```

Does the new standard support anything of that kind?

**Update**: this article describes how to implement a range generator in C++11: [Generator in C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)#C++)

Comment: Why do you want to loop over a range of integers in the first place?

Comment: @Xeo, are you serious? Looping over a range of integers is (I'm pretty certain) in _every_ piece of C source that isn't a simple `HelloWorld` program. Or did you mean: why would you want to use the range-based `for` for that?

Comment: @paxdiablo: I'm dead-serious. Give me a good reason to loop over a range of integers. Do you use those integers to index something? Loop / iterate over that something instead. Explicit loops are highly error-prone. The only time I effectively use them is for benchmark loops.

Comment: Boost.Range has irange.

Comment: @paxdiablo: C source is irrelevant. The question clearly explicitly pertains to C++11.

Comment: @Xeo, I get you now. You have a good point except for one small use case (one I've discovered in many for/foreach questions). Sometimes you _need_ to know the index. Granted that's probably a small use case but I can envisage a couple of things that might need it - just the other day, I had my boy doing a 12-times table program albeit not in C++ since I believe that would be cruel punishment for a 9yo :-)

Comment: @Xeo: There have been many times when I've needed to loop over a range of integers, if for no other reason than to loop over a container *and* have access to the index at the same time.

Comment: @paxdiablo: That's when you zip range you're iterating on with an infinite integer range. Painful in C++ but well it's C++.

Comment: @Nicol: See the above two comments.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah exactly, *C* code. Just that this question isn't about *C*, which doesn't have a range based for, anyway. Though I agree that there are indeed use-cases for iterating over a range of integers, just not that many as in *C* (and it hurts everytime I need to use an index loop instead of an iterator loop ;), but that may be just be).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

While its not provided by C++11, you can write your own view or use the one from boost:

```
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (auto i : boost::irange(1, 10))
        std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

Moreover, [`Boost.Range`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) contains a few more interesting ranges which you could find pretty useful combined with the new `for` loop. For example, you can get a [reversed view](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html).

Comment: Basically, one can implement a class which fullfills requirements of range based for on their own.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow, I've chosen bad wording. Updated now.

Comment: Do you happen to know of a minimal C++14/C++17 self-contained implementation of `irange`?

Comment: @ixSci: Come on, using heap? This would be [terribly difficult for compilers](https://godbolt.org/g/vcPKXc).

Comment: @einpoklum, you asked for a small self-contained implementation. Do not like mine? Come up with your own.

Comment: @ixSci: Ok, fair enough, but my point is that an implementation needs to (easily) translate into the same instructions as the plain for loop, and creating an std::vector, on the heap, is not that.

Comment: @einpoklum, you can always create a wrapper class which will conform to for loop interface which will be eliminated by a compiler on compile time and which will be just a simple number generator. But it will require more code and a little bit of thinking. That will also be not that small probably. Different needs — different implementations. If you just need a small implementation which is used in non-hot paths where you do not care about a malloc or two then my 5-min-to-write implementation might be appropriate. Otherwise we have to wait for co-routines for small **and** efficient impl.

Comment: Alternatively, with range-v3 library you can do `for (auto i : ranges::view::iota(1, 10))`.

Answer (score 41):

With `C++20` we <s>will</s> have *ranges*. If you don't have access to C++20, you can try them out by downloading the lastest stable release from it's author, Eric Niebler, from [his github](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), or go to [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LzHfd7Vvi8FgAN12). What you are interested in is `ranges::views::iota`, which makes this code legal:

```
#include <range/v3/view/iota.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace ranges;
    
    for (const int i : views::iota(1, 10)) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

What's great about this approach is that `view`s are *lazy*. This means that even though `views::iota` represents a range from `1` to `10` exclusive, no more than one `int` from that range exists at a given time. The elements are *generated on demand*.

If you *do* have access to C++20, this version works out of the box:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {  
    for (const int i : std::views::iota(1, 10)) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: ranges-v3 is not usable with C++11 AFAICT, only C++14; and this question is about C++11 - it's tagged as such and OP said as much in the body.

Comment: @einpoklum I believe they can be used with C++11. Didn't test it though - I believe Eric Niebler, during one of his talk, stated that they are compatible with C++11.

Comment: The library documentation [says C++14 and up](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/). Also - if it's not too much trouble, would you mind telling me at exactly which time you answered this question (it's related to some argument on meta)? I'm only seeing the hour-resolution time.

Comment: @einpoklum you are right regarding the documantation. I must have either remembered incorrectly or it must have been changed after Eric's talk in 2015 (highly likely). Regarding the exact timestamp - I do not remember that and I am not aware of SO tool that would allow me to check that. As an author of the answer - can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps you should include less than all of range/v3 ?

Comment: What's nice about this is that you can mark your iterator variable `i` `const`.

Comment: And to elaborate on @bers comment, marking the iterator variable `const` informs the reader you do not expect it to be tinkered with in the loop and tells the compiler to enforce that expectation. If you do this consistently in a project, then absence of `const` is a flag to the reader it *will* get tinkered with. Example of Kate Gregory's "saying nothing": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYVxGyido9g

Answer (score 40):

The neatest way is still this:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
```

I guess you can do this, but I wouldn't call it so neat:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  for ( auto i : { 1,2,3,4,5 } )
  {
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give +1 just for that first sentence. Sometimes the old ways are still the best :-)

Comment: Unless n is an expensive expression of course, then irange is concise and performant.

Comment: This is not neat. It has three (or two if you want to split hairs) different imperative statements, which you have to put together to realize it's a loop. Not neat at all. Plus, it doesn't indicate whether `i` is significant or whether the author just wanted to run a piece of code `n` times.

Comment: @einpoklum: "neatest" != "neat, according to some implicit gold standard". All it meant was "no better alternative in pure, bare-foot C++ yet, _unfortunately_".

Comment: I've typed `for (int j=0; j<n; ++i)` by mistake a few too many times for me to feel that that's neat.

Comment: I was looking for a "neater" solution from another point of view: Due to `i`'s incrementation, `i` cannot be `const` although one might want to express that `i` shouldn't be modified (besides being incremented). The second solution, while not being "so neat", at least allows for making `i` `const`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind doing the loop in reverse order, you can replace

`for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)`

with simpler

`for (int i=n; i--;)`

Comment: I think `for (int i=n; --i;)` is the correct translation in reverse order. With the usage of `i--` you are accessing index `n` up to index `1` which is not the same and can cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have to do with the integer, consider the also the `<numeric>` header, in particular 
[`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) in conjunction with `std::transform` and `std::fill` depending on the cases.

Comment: How can I trust the compiler to optimize all of that away and make it a simple loop again? Especially since you might need an auxiliary vector for the 0...n-1 values.

Comment: If you don't trust compiler optimization, use C not C++.

Comment: I'm not talking about _that_ kind of compiler optimization. I'm talking those that are more out-there, like removing malloc and free calls when the compiler can tell they're not actually necessary, which is what you would need here.

Answer (score -3):

Well, I really like the solution, provided [here](https://habr.com/ru/post/516630/) (I'm sorry, it's not translated in English):

```
#define FOR(I,UPPERBND) for(int I = 0; I<int(UPPERBND); ++I)
```

The main idea is described in this way: when we talk about simple iteration-indexed-cycles, we do not need to think about it. However, when we use for(;;) construction- there are always three steps: initialization, end condition check, iteration. And this is an overkill for such a simple loop, as just i:[0,n).
I liked the idea, that we want to write simple things in a simple way. When you see that FOR(i,N) - you just know, that there are nothing special. When you see the for(;;) construction - you have to be more careful and see all three parts of it.
Just an example from that article:

```
for (int iter=0; iter<nb_iter; iter++) {          // some iterative computation
    for (int c=0; c<mesh.cells.nb(); c++)         // loop through all tetrahedra
        for (int lv0=0; lv0<4; lv0++)             // for every pair of
            for (int lv1 = lv0+1; lv1<4; lv1++)   // vertices in the tet
                for (int d=0; d<3; d++) {         // do stuff for each of 3 dimensions
                    nlRowScaling(weight);
                    nlBegin(NL_ROW);
                    nlCoefficient(mesh.cells.vertex(c, lv0)*3 + d,  1);
                    nlCoefficient(mesh.cells.vertex(c, lv1)*3 + d, -1);
                    nlEnd(NL_ROW);
                }
    [...]
}
```

become a:

```
FOR(iter, nb_iter) {
    FOR(c, mesh.cells.nb())
        FOR(lv0, 4)
            for (int lv1 = lv0+1; lv1<4; lv1++)
                FOR(d, 3) {
                    nlRowScaling(weight);
                    nlBegin(NL_ROW);
                    nlCoefficient(mesh.cells.vertex(c, lv0)*3 + d,  1);
                    nlCoefficient(mesh.cells.vertex(c, lv1)*3 + d, -1);
                    nlEnd(NL_ROW);
                }
    [...]
}
```

And you see, where you should concentrate your attention.