# Iteration boundaries same as data type's

Tags: go, overflow

A function I have takes *min*, *max* `uint16` parameters and at some point iterates over the numeric range. However, if *max* happens to be **2^16-1** (and it is a valid use case), then overflow breaks the loop logic. Here is an example code demonstrating the problem with `uint8`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func iter(min, max uint8) {
    for i := min; i <= max; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d, ", i)
    }
}

func main() {
    iter(0, 255)
}
```

As you can see, the program never ends. A similar question was asked at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950244) but the solution exactly exhibits the same problem I have.

My thinking for now is to convert the loop variable to `uint32`, similar to this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func iter(min, max uint8) {
    for i := uint16(min); i <= uint16(max); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d, ", i)
    }
}

func main() {
    iter(0, 255)
}
```

However, this seems to be a clumsy solution, which is not going to work for `uint64` or whatever biggest `uintN` type. Feels like I am missing something very basic. Guidance?

I am aware of [Brad Fitz's Iter solution](https://github.com/bradfitz/iter/blob/master/iter.go), but it seems to add unneeded overhead. Is that true as well?

Comment: I have a hacky solution for you, instead of iterating up to `max` inclusive, iterate up to `max` exclusive. This way an overflow is never reached.

Comment: I gather this is the style you suggest? https://gist.githubusercontent.com/didenko/ed5144f6349656c683dc/raw/3a4b2d1c565819f54604a97409e6b6b0d0fe50b8/max_special.go

Comment: @VladDidenko: What output do you get for `iter(42, 7)`? https://gist.githubusercontent.com/didenko/ed5144f6349656c683dc/raw/3a4b2d1c565819f54604a97409e6b6b0d0fe50b8/max_special.go

Comment: @peterSO argh you are right, more cruft to get rid of the hanging max run. Not worth it.

Comment: BTW, as mentioned in the answers below, the cleanest (for `uint8` or `uint16` inputs) is to just convert to `uint` (instead of `uint32`!, if you're going to convert you may as well use the native integer size). Especially if you don't need to use the index the as an `uint8` within the loop that will probably also be the fastest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, for `uint8`,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func iter(min, max uint8) {
    {
        min, max := uint(min), uint(max)
        for i := min; i <= max; i++ {
            fmt.Printf("%d, ", i)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    iter(0, 255)
}
```

For `uint64`,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func iter(min, max uint64) {
    for i := min; i <= max; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d, ", i)
        if i == max {
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    iter(^uint64(0)-2, ^uint64(0))
}
```

Output:

```
18446744073709551613, 18446744073709551614, 18446744073709551615
```

**Addendum**:

Here's my version of [Dave C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55504/dave-c)'s [suggestion](https://play.golang.org/p/lSJFw2Tje_).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func iter(min, max uint64) {
    for i, next := min, min <= max; next; i, next = i+1, i < max {
        fmt.Printf("%#016[1]x ", i)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}

func main() {
    const maxUint64 = ^uint64(0)
    iter(0, 3)
    iter(10, 9)
    iter(maxUint64-2, maxUint64)
}
```

Output:

```
0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000001 0x0000000000000002 0x0000000000000003 
0xfffffffffffffffd 0xfffffffffffffffe 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: Note in the later case you need to make sure not to use `continue` before the conditional. Also the `for` condition becomes redundant so just `for i := min; ; i++ {` if you like.

Comment: Is there a significant difference between the first version in the answer and the one suggested in the question?
The second one, after Dave's suggestion may look like this: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/didenko/ed5144f6349656c683dc/raw/e8d14b04700d9a26a4c5140219c811ec4ccb7a5c/check_in_body.go
I am concerned about the need to memorize the danger of "continue" before the test, so if a function call is not an issue the a version in the question comments looks somewhat preferable. Do I miss something?

Comment: @DaveC: Whenever you change code you must be sure that you don't introduce bugs. You can do that in many ways. For example, by introducing an errant `continue` or by following your suggestion about removing the `for` statement `i <= max` condition, which  will change the behavior of the `iter` function whenever `min > max`.

Comment: @peterSO note about the min > max case makes sense. I like special-case of max processing from Benjamin Gruenbaum even more after these considerations.

Comment: @peterSO, gah, you are absolutely right, I completely forgot about `min > max`! I was too focused on not doing two comparisons each loop. If that was a concern, it might make more sense to have an `if min > max {return}` at the start to correctly eliminate the double compare. Your original is cleaner/nicer though. It's a trade off between simplicity and efficiency I think.

Comment: BTW, [here](https://play.golang.org/p/lSJFw2Tje_) is simple (put perhaps hard to read) way to avoid the extra comparisons and yet "do the right thing", including allowing `continue` anywhere after the first line of the loop.

Comment: @DaveC: Nice. I would simplify it. See my revised answer.

Comment: BTW, if anyone is wondering about that `%…[1]x`, it was a left over from when I was doing something like `Printf("%d = %[1]x", i)`. It should probably be removed now, sorry. (And I only used hex since I the decimal of maxUint64 doesn't mean much to me :).