# How to iterate a specific number of times in a Go template?

Tags: go, hugo

I'm converting an erb template to a Go template (using Hugo), and I'm trying to create a specific number of identical `<div>`s. Ruby has the [times](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-times) iterator, which worked well in the erb template. I assume there's something similar in Go, but I'm having a hard time finding it.

in Erb:

```
<% 100.times.each do |i| %>
  <div class='star'></div>
<% end %>
```

I see that Go templates allow to iterate over a collection using `range`, but it's unclear how to do the above in a Go template without explicitly creating a collection with 100 items.

This question has some information on iterating a specific number of times in Go, but is not in the context of Go templates:
[Is there a way to iterate over a range of integers in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950244/is-there-a-way-to-iterate-over-a-range-of-integers-in-golang)

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Golang code to repeat an html code n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112679/golang-code-to-repeat-an-html-code-n-times/46112802#46112802).

Answer (score 5):

I found that [seq](https://gohugo.io/functions/seq/) was what I was looking for:

```
{{ range seq 100 }}
  <div class='star'></div>
{{ end }}
```