# c++ shorter way to display the next 5 numbers by given inputs?

Tags: c++, sequential

i've just learned cpp and want to know is there a shorter way to display a sequential number.

this is my code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;

    cout<<"Input number: ";
    cin>>n;

    cout<<"The next 5 rows of number is :"<<n+1<<n+2<<n+3<<n+4<<n+5;
}
```

Comment: How about loops? Perhaps it's time you [find a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neatest way to loop over a range of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088900/neatest-way-to-loop-over-a-range-of-integers)

Comment: You use a loop for that usually.

Comment: "rows upwards" is a strange way to describe what you're doing.  It seems to me like you want to "display the next 5 numbers".

Comment: sorry for my bad english, yes that's what i meant. display the next 5 numbers.

Comment: I swear if this was the Java tag there would've already been 10 answers showing how to use a loop from 100 rep users.

Comment: There are better ways to do it, but what actually do you want? the easiest? the shortest? the most correct one?

Comment: actually i want to learn many ways to show it, but the shortest or the most correct is okay. can you write it?

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) { cout << n+i << ";" }`

Comment: You could pitch it on [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and see what the hardcore "shorter way" crowd comes up with.

Comment: @StephanLechner Answers go in the answer section mate

Comment: Your code may actually be more efficient than using a loop.  When the processor encounters a branch or jump, it has to decide if the instruction cache needs to be reloaded.  A`for` loop would execute 5 times (5 jumps), whereas your addition statements don't use jumps or branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop should solve your problem:

```
int main(){
    int n;

    cout << "Input number: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "The next 5 rows of number are: ";

    for (int i = n + 1; i <= n + 5; i++) {
        cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it's deliberately ironical that this code is longer than the original.

Comment: Well kinda, but i now understand how to implement looping for my code hehe