# What does the following code do?

Tags: c++

I was wondering what the following code does:

```
for (auto x:m) std::cout << x << " ";
```

I already know that `auto` is a way to leave it to the compiler to decide the type of the variable but I don't know what `:m` does.

Comment: m is probably a container: so for each element (x) in your container (m): print x

Comment: Can you tell us what is `m`?

Comment: C++11 - the new ISO C++ standard [Unordered containers](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [range-based for in c++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005835/range-based-for-in-c11)

Comment: m is surely a container. See second answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702561/c-iterate-through-vector-using-for-loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a C++11 range-based `for` loop syntax described here: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html

Here `m` should be a container, like std::vector. The code will iterate the container and put every element (accessed as `x` inside the loop) into the `std::cout` stream. Elements will be separated by space.

Comment: does it work on c++10 as well?

Comment: You mean C++03? No, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

`m` is any type that follows the ranged concept (i.e. [Container concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container)).

The loop iterates over all elements of `m` where `x` represents the currently iterated value.

Comment: `m` can also be an array or a user defined type. It doesn't have to fully satisfy the container concept.

Comment: @juanchopanza I didn't say `m` is a container.